# Get Weather information using Yql query lat,long parms

Tags: yql, yahoo-weather-api

I am using the following YQL query to get weather information

http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20item%20from%20weather.forecast%20where%20location%3D%2248907%22&format=json

Is there any way to get weather information using longitude, latitude as YQL query parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a sub-select to go from a latitude/longitude pair to a [WOEID](http://developer.yahoo.com/geo/geoplanet/guide/concepts.html) like

```
SELECT * FROM weather.woeid 
WHERE w IN (
    SELECT place.woeid 
    FROM flickr.places(1) 
    WHERE (lat,lon) in (55.948503,-3.198931)
);
```

([Try in YQL console](http://y.ahoo.it/myqoOKhr))

Comment: This no longer works. I get this error in the YQL console: `Cannot find required keys in where clause; got 'lat, lon', expecting required keys: (api_key,query) OR (lon,api_key,lat)`

Comment: You'll need to send along a [Flickr API key](http://www.flickr.com/services/api/misc.api_keys.html) as well... For example ([console](http://y.ahoo.it/cwT9g)) `set api_key="2319d15…" on flickr.places; select * from weather.woeid…`

Comment: Dead link: "Try in YQL console"

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

...

```
query = "SELECT * FROM weather.forecast " +
            "WHERE woeid in (" +
            "SELECT woeid " +
            "FROM geo.places(1) " +
            "WHERE text=\"(%1$s,  %2$s)\") " +
            "AND u='c'";
```

... and then:

```
query = String.format(query, location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
```

Answer (score -1):

I have found some thing use ful; if you need to forcast weather yql use the 
SELECT * FROM weather.bylocation WHERE location='Indonesia' 
select * from weather.forecast where location=90210